# generating all representations of n 1's in a zero matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a way to generate all combinations of nXn matrices of n 1's with all other locations containing 0's.  For example, if I start off with a 3x3 zero matrix

```
dim = 3
m = np.zeros((dim, dim), dtype=np.int)
```

- If n is 0, there is 1 possible representation.
- If n is 1, there are 9 representations.
- If n is 2, there are 72 (9 * 8) representations.

That is, if n is i, there are (dim * dim)!/((dim * dim) - i)! representations.

It seems that the generator solution yielding dim*dim matrices of n 1's takes the parameters **dim** and **n** and generates the **(dim * dim)!/((dim * dim) - i)!** representations.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generator of these kinds of matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

def generate_representations(dim, n, dtype=int):
    assert n <= dim * dim

    for ind in combinations(range(dim * dim), n):
        mat = np.zeros(dim * dim, dtype=dtype)
        if ind:
            mat[np.array(ind)] = 1
        yield mat.reshape(dim, dim)
```

It returns a generator of unique `dim` x `dim` matrices with entries consisting of `n` ones, and the remaining entries zero.

Note that for `dim=3` and `n=2`, it correctly removes duplicates and returns 36 results (`9 * 8 / 2`), not the 72 you'd indicated in your question:

```
mats = list(generate_representations(3, 2))
len(mats)
# 36

mats[10]
# array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```